# jQuery SlidesJS keyboard navigation

Tags: jquery, slideshow, keyboard-navigation

My [site](http://burnettfam.com/photos/first-week/) uses [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/) for a photo slideshow.

My question is, how can I use keyboard navigation?

I've added this [GitHub solution](https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides/issues/183#issuecomment-1749133) to my head tag (lines 94-116) but the keyboard's left & right arrow keys still aren't working.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I input the following code into the console window on chrome when on the SlidesJS site and it worked...

```
(function($){
    $(window).keyup(function(e){
        var key = e.which | e.keyCode;
        if(key === 37){ // 37 is left arrow
            $('a.prev').click();
        }
        else if(key === 39){ // 39 is right arrow
            $('a.next').click();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Edited for compatibility with pages that don't normally use $ for jQuery.

Comment: the site is using jQuery instead of $ though.  Other than that this should be perfect.

Comment: Awesome - works perfectly! I appreciate the edit as well. I tried to award the bounty but it says I can't award for 22 hours. Will do that tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the keyup events to the window context and fire the click event on the next and prev buttons based on `event.keyCode`

```
jQuery(window).bind("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 37) {
        jQuery(".prev").click();
    } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        jQuery(".next").click(); 
    }
});
```

There should be some code in there to change the thumbs but that's the basic functionality off the top of my head.

Comment: @Gísli Konráð Well... not *exactly* the same... about 1 minute slower :P  I was/am planing on removing mine as soon as you get the chance to change $ to jQuery.  No other point to having mine up other than that :P

Comment: It's effectively the same. No need to delete your answer... You use jQuery in yours, I user $ (but populate $ with the jQuery object in my recent edit)